# Phpunit, Laravel - отрабатывает только любой первый тест из списка

Tags: php, laravel5, phpunit

Phpunit, Laravel - отрабатывает только любой первый тест из списка.
На все последующие тесты получаю ошибку

Exception: PhpConsole\Connector::setPostponeStorage can be called only before PhpConsole\Connector::getInstance()

> /root/vendor/php-console/php-console/src/PhpConsole/Connector.php:81
>   /root/vendor/php-console/laravel-service-provider/src/PhpConsole/Laravel/ServiceProvider.php:103
>   /root/vendor/php-console/laravel-service-provider/src/PhpConsole/Laravel/ServiceProvider.php:86
>   /root/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/BoundMethod.php:29
>   /root/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/BoundMethod.php:87
>   /root/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/BoundMethod.php:31
>   /root/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php:549
>   /root/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Application.php:792
>   /root/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Application.php:775
>   /root/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Application.php:776
>   /root/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Bootstrap/BootProviders.php:17
>   /root/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Application.php:213
>   /root/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Console/Kernel.php:296
>   /root/tests/CreatesApplication.php:20
>   /root/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Testing/TestCase.php:91
>   /root/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Testing/TestCase.php:68

```
namespace MyPackage\Tests\Feature;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\DatabaseTransactions;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\WithoutMiddleware;
use Tests\TestCase;    
class MyTest extends TestCase
{

    use DatabaseTransactions;
    use WithoutMiddleware;

    /**
     * A basic test example.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function testBasicTest1()
    {
        $this->assertTrue(true);
    }

    /**
     * A basic test example.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function testBasicTest2()
    {
        $this->assertTrue(true);
    }

    /**
     * A basic test example.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function testBasicTest3()
    {
        $this->assertTrue(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: Пример теста можно?

Comment: добавил пример класса теста

Comment: Вы используете PhpConsole как поставщик услуг в Laravel, проверьте где он инициализирует библиотеку консоли как указано в https://packagist.org/packages/php-console/php-console?page=5 - либо через getInstance, либо через register.